# What are Some Real World Usage Scenarios for node.js

Tags: node.js

i would like to begin tinkering with Node.js but i am unsure of some "Real-World" situations where node.js would be considered the proper thing to be used. The last thing a developer wants is to learn a new technology and use it in-properly..

Can you provide real-world examples of where node.js would be used properly

Comment: CoffeScript compiler. Meteor.js. If you just wanted a list, then the question is off topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web apps server side, that is, apps that handle lots of network traffic and optionally lots of disk traffic. Node.js's main strength is non-blocking io (network as well as disc).

Comment: I can imagine NodeJS useful in making simple REST-like API's for heavy I/O data transfers (such as fetching data from databases, key-value stores, etc).

Comment: It's a general use language platform. It would have been better to have asked what can't you use it for.